# Wildcard Query in Zend Lucene

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-search-lucene

```
$index = Zend_Search_Lucene::open("/data/my_index1");

$doc = new Zend_Search_Lucene_Document();

$doc->addField(Zend_Search_Lucene_Field::Text('type','auto'));

$index->addDocument($doc);

$term = new Zend_Search_Lucene_Index_Term('auto*');

$query = new Zend_Search_Lucene_Search_Query_Wildcard($term);

$hits  = $index->find($query);

foreach ($hits as $hit){

    echo $hit->type;

}
```

After successful execution of this code, it needs to print auto. But array $hits is empty.

What is the reason behind this?

Comment: sorry in the title instead of fuzzy it has to be wildcard

Comment: Edited question for better readability / understanding.

Answer (score 1):

Two years late, but the likely reason is that your changes are not committed to the index. After the document has been added, you need to call commit method to make it available for searching.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to humour me here, but have you tried replacing:

```
$term = new Zend_Search_Lucene_Index_Term('auto*');

$query = new Zend_Search_Lucene_Search_Query_Wildcard($term);

$hits  = $index->find($query);
```

with

```
$hits  = $index->find('auto*');
```